# Titlesec section headings right-centered

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I have a problem with the section headings using the titlesec-package. I want to have all the titles left-aligned. However, when I write longer titles such as "Peer-reviewed Publications" then "Peer-reviewed" is left-aligned and "Publications" is right-aligned with a big gap in between. How can I bring the whole title to the left-hand sinde?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {currvita}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \thispagestyle{empty}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\begin{document}
\date{}
\centering 
\begingroup
    \fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont
\textbf{sdfsdf} 
\endgroup

\raggedright
\section*{Education} 

\section*{Peer-reviewed Publications}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `\centering` and `\raggedright`.

It's generally not recommendable to use `\centering` at the top level, because it's hard to get back to normal typesetting. A general rule with LaTeX is to use grouping for such changes. However, just interchanging `\centering` and `\begingroup` would not do, because the text would end up justified. Much better is to use the `center` environment.

While `\raggedright` may be used at the top level, if one wants ragged right typesetting, you have to help `titlesec`, because it doesn't assume it and, as you saw, it produces wrong results.

My suggestion is to use standard justified typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
  [{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries
sdfsdf
\end{center}

\section{Education}

\section{Peer-reviewed Publications}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you seem to be using unnumbered sections throughout, instead of `\section*` it's better to set the counter for the numbering depth.

Finally, using `\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}` is wrong in several aspects. The first of which is that you don't get a 15pt font (you find a warning in your log file); second, the distances between lines would appear to be random.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `\raggedright` to the `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {currvita}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \thispagestyle{empty}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedright}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\begin{document}
\date{}
\centering 
\begingroup
    \fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont
\textbf{sdfsdf} 
\endgroup

\raggedright
\section*{Education} 

\section*{Peer-reviewed Publications} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `\filright` command defined by the package. I suppose it must do something more than `\raggedright` in this context.